# Smart contract compiling loop

Tags: smart-contract

When I try to compile the contract the process creates an infinite loop. Here is my code, please help!

#### kjnjrwsyxszg.cpp

```
#include "kjnjrwsyxszg.hpp"
void kjnjrwsyxszg::create(const name owner, const string name, const uint64_t attack)
{
    // Instantiate items_table
    items_table items(_self, _self.value);

    // Create and set item
    items.emplace(owner, [&](auto &item) {
        item.id = items.available_primary_key();
        item.name = name;
        item.attack = attack;
        item.owner = owner;
    });
}
```

#### kjnjrwsyxszg.hpp

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class[[eosio::contract("kjnjrwsyxszg")]] kjnjrwsyxszg : public eosio::contract
{
public:
    using contract::contract;

    [[eosio::action]] void create(const name owner, const string name, const uint64_t attack);

private:
    // @abi table items i64
    struct [[eosio::table]] Item
    {
        uint64_t id;
        string name;
        uint64_t attack;
        eosio::name owner;

        auto primary_key() const { return id; };
    };

    typedef multi_index<"items"_n, Item> items_table;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if one of these solves your issue but try to leave out the additional "void" and use ACTION instead of [[eosio::action]].

**kjnjrwsyxszg.cpp**

```
#include "kjnjrwsyxszg.hpp"
ACTION kjnjrwsyxszg::create(const name owner, const string name, const uint64_t attack)
```

**kjnjrwsyxszg.hpp**

```
using namespace eosio;
...
CONTRACT kjnjrwsyxszg : public contract
{
public:
    using contract::contract;

    ACTION create(const name owner, const string name, const uint64_t attack);
...
```

*The following is wrong, see Phillips comment below*

you are also missing the Dispatcher in your .cpp

```
EOSIO_DISPATCH(kjnjrwsyxszg, (create))
```

Comment: `EOSIO_DISPATCH` is no longer needed in the most recent versions of `eosio.cdt`.
As for using `[[eosio::action]] void`, there is no difference between this and `ACTION`, except that using the attributes allows you to give a different name to the action in the ABI file and the function name. For example: `[[eosio::action("create")]] void create_character` would make an action called `create`, but in your code you can have a better name like `create_character`

Comment: Oh. I've missed that.